# Ubuntu 18.04 Keyboard Layout Bug

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

My problem is that whichever keyboard layout  I choose as second keyboard layout, it is always english qwerty. How can I solve this bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have somehow managed the situtation. I just randomly include and exclude keyboard layouts and after a long time I found the true keyboard layout. It is just too weird and every time I install 18.04 I am encountering with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem. I solved it by adding my second language, then I‌ removed the English(main language) and I could type in the second language. Then I added the English layout again and the problem was fixed.